# postgresql identical table's size are different

Tags: postgresql-9.5

My initial problem started when employer hired me as a report developer but on the first day of job gave me DBA tasks. So, please tolerate my insufficient to non existent knowledge of DBA skills.

So about DB. it is PostgreSQL Amazon RDS. DB size is 127 GB (and current concern/problem of mine).

This size is too big for a company of 3 (+some month) years that surely does not have that much of data recordings.

After examining bit deeper I was able to pinpoint few tables that were taking almost up to 90% of that 127GB.

One of those tables lets call it table X is 23GB in size (external size 14GB). count of records is only 366541. with 36 columns out of which only 5 are string types  rest is integer, bool, serial and timestamp.

One of the thoughts that came to my mind was the actual text that was being saved in on of the columns is a reason for the table size.

After examining the data, I saw that all the text that was repeating for this records were already stored as a single records in different tables. So to test my theory I decided to break this string data into FK columns and check if this would cause difference in size.

But after structure and data cloning of this table, new table on test DB is much much smaller, 200 MB. I compared everything column types, data, count of it, server parameters, everything is the same. only one difference is that test table has no FKs anymore. columns and its data is there but column itself is not FK-ed(referenced).

What am I missing? What is the thing that is causing table to be this big in size?

Comment: Most probably [table bloat](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat) (usually caused by wrong transaction handling). Check if [`vacuum full the_table;`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/VACUUM_FULL)  reduces the size as expected.